# Isomerisation Reactions of Alkyl Halides

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, isomers

My organic chemistry textbook says:

> Haloalkanes on heating at 573K or in presence of anhydrous at low temperature undergo molecular rearrangement to form an isomeric haloalkane. [image]

I noticed a similarity in these two examples. In both cases, a primary halide was getting converted into a secondary hailde.

Now, can somebody show the actual mechanism of this isomerisation reaction? Also, does the phenomenon I mentioned have something to do with the mechanism?

Comment: Note that this occurs at high temperature or in the presence of a Lewis acid. The intermediate is the AlCl3X anion - alkyl cation ion pair (X = halogen). You get a hydride shift to give the most stable alkyl cation